# Function to verify if the values in the second array correspond to the square values of the first array

Tags: php

I want to have a function that returns true if the values of the second array are the square of the values of the first array. Like this is not working because it returns always true. Do you know where is the issue?

```
function verify($arrayA, $arrayB){
    for($a=0; $a <= count($arrayA); $a++){
            if(in_array(pow($arrayA[$a], 2), $arrayB)){
                echo "y";
                return true;
            }
            else{
                echo "n";
                return false;
             }
    }
}

$arrayA = [1, 2, 2];
$arrayB = [1,7,8];

$result = verify($arrayA, $arrayB);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Think about this: how many times will your `foreach` loop iterate? Are you sure? ;-)

Comment: Why not just use a foreach loop to loop through the array?

Comment: Can arrayB contain not a square  value of the first array.f.e. [3.3] and [1,9] ? Should values and it's square be ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exit the loop in the first iteration .... always.

In case the square is in the other array, you should not exit the loop, but continue checking for the next one. Only when the loop can make all iterations (without returning false), you can conclude it is ok:

```
function verify($arrayA, $arrayB){
    for($a=0; $a <= count($arrayA); $a++){
        if(!in_array(pow($arrayA[$a], 2), $arrayB)){
            echo "n";
            return false;
         }
    }
    echo "y";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This still suffers from the second bullet point of @Adrien's answer.

Comment: @TravisHegner, That depends on what exactly is the desired behaviour. I did not get from the question that the square must be at the exact same index.

Comment: Indeed, the second, I corrected it. I interpreted the question as meaning the same index, but I suppose it could have been interpreted differently.

Comment: Consider declaring an external bool variable and instead of doing return true or false, set that variable instead. $inArray=true or $inArray=false

Comment: @RussJ, since it is a function, and further looping makes no sense once the result is certain, a `return` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here:

- First, you only check the first array element because you exit your function both if your condition is true or false, you should return false if the current element of `$arrayB` is not equal to the squared current element of `$arrayA`, continue processing otherwise.
- Secondly, you use in_array() function, which looks in all the `$arrayB` array, so your function will return true if all element in `$arrayA` have their squared value in `$arrayB` no matter of the order and number of occurrences. You should check `$arrayA[$a]` and `$arrayB[$a]` elements.